# TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable when trying to check for a None value

Tags: python, typeerror, nonetype

This is the error I receive:

```
line 16, in main
    definition, data = get_name ()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

I check for `None` type here:

```
definition = get_word (name, gender)

if definition is None:
     print ("\"" + non_lower + "\"", "not found.")
else:
     return definition
```

Here is the code which will return `None` if the search term is not found:

```
if x and new_line is not None:
    return new_line, x
```

I am returning 2 values but it is returning one value and when I try to check that value for a `None` I get the error. If there anyway to check the variable for `None` correctly so if nothing is returned I can present a message?

Comment: Your question is somewhat unclear. Regardless, the called function (which you haven't shown) should always return the same number of values even if both of them are `None` — and you should always call it expecting that many values to be returned.

Comment: Please provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You have a double negative in the part that is returning `None` for the check later. Maybe try this:

```
if x and new_line:
    return new_line, x
else:
    return None, None
```

Then when checking for `None` don't actually check for `None`, check the variable is something other than `None`, then catch `None` with the else statement?

```
if definition:
    return definition
else:
    print ("\"" + non_lower + "\"", "not found.")
```